# setting the value in a column equal to the product of two other columns in flex

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, product

I have this spark DataGrid with five columns. my third and fourth columns represent amount (of product ordered) and price (of a unit of the product). My issue now is to set the fifth column equal to price*amount. I can't seem to find a way to do this. anyone? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that amount and price are stored in the objects that populate your DataGrid.

Just create a custom itemRenderer for the fifth column.  In the dataChange event calculate the value.  Conceptually something like this:

```
protected function onDataChange(event:Event):void{
  myDisplayField.text = (data.amount*data.price).toString();
}
```

[More info on creating custom renderers.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html)